# Magento 2.2.5: Search Wish List

Tags: magento2.2, search, wishlist

I'm doing Search Wish List.

Everything i have done til now is create a CRUD module. So, I'm not very clear about this.

[image]

The idea is type something in the Search box on the top right. And after that, it go to this url : `http://localhost/magento/fudu/wishlistsearch/result/?q=Way`.
For example, i type "Way" and then push enter.

After that, it should appear Product in Wish List that have name `like "Way"`.